# Запись масива в несколько TextBox. Перебор классов

Tags: c#, массивы, textbox

Есть несколько десятков TextBox-ов и есть масив с значениями для них. Писать `TextBox1.Text = array[0] ....... Textbox20.Text = array[19]` не вариант. Надо способ записать все эти значения в цикле, но я не знаю как перебирать TextBox1-TextBox20 для записи в них значений.
Прошу помощи если кто-то знает как это сделать.

Язык C#

Comment: Так возьмите все контолы и перебирайте, зачем тут вообще обращение по имени и прочее? Взять все (я так понимаю у вас WinForms) - `.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()`.

Comment: Благодарю, всё вышло)